# Session reset without session_destroy is valid?

Tags: php, session

I'm trying to destroy the session without using `session_destroy` because I want to carry the information message. My question is if my code is valid, I already reset the session by saying all `$_SESSION` is an empty array or for security reason using the `session_destroy` is a must but if I use session_destoy I can't pass the `$_SESSION['msg']` anymore.

```
<?
session_start();
$_SESSION = array();
//session_destoy();
$_SESSION['msg'] = "You have logged out.";
header('Location: index.php');
?>
```

Comment: what deos " because I want to carry the information message" mean ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `session_unset()`

> session_unset just clears out the session for usage. The session is
>   still on the users computer. Note that by using session_unset, the
>   variable still exists. session_unset just remove all session
>   variables. it does not destroy the session....so the session would
>   still be active.

via: http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-unset.php

and then you can do it like

```
$_SESSION['msg'] = "You have logged out.";
```

so that the `msg` is added to session.

**OR You can do it like this too:**

```
$msg ="Whatever the message is"; 
header("Location: index.php?message=$msg ");
```

In index.php file

```
if(isset($_GET['message']) && !empty($_GET['message'])){ 
  echo $_GET['message']; 
}
```

Comment: or I can use $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"] to generate the message if I came from logout.php

Comment: Yeah my bad I just forgot what session_unset does, so I just unset the username session and the message can still pass. Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

1st you should use `session_unset();` to remove all session variables/values rather than assigning a new array to it.

The main answer to your query:

I would recommend to use `session_destroy()` because it removes the internal session ID generated which would be validated at every request coming from a client device. To verify this, just print the session ID using the function `echo session_id();` before and after emptying the session in the way you are doing. It would pring the same session ID.
So destroying it first and then creating new will be a good idea.

Once you destroy the session using `session_destroy()` you can start a new session again and set your message `$_SESSION['msg']` in it.

Comment: I just realised I can make another trick, to check from which page I came from when I am redirected to index.php which is the login area and I can use $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"] and if I came from logout.php to generate the message "You have logged out."

Comment: But @John, you will not get any `HTTP_REFERER` if you would have opened the page in new tab.

Comment: Thank you @John, for voting up. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use cookies; you would keep for example the username, the password and the connection status of the user. When the user comes back to your site, you know who he is and if he is already connected.

```
setcookie ("Msg", "you have logged out", time () + 3600);
```

(for a cookie of one hour, you put the time that you want ...)

Answer (score 0):

Just user `session_unset($_SESSION['session_name']);` hope this will work.

Comment: This is exactly what I did.

Answer (score 0):

Your code:

```
<?
session_start();
$_SESSION = array();
//session_destoy();
$_SESSION['msg'] = "You have logged out.";
header('Location: index.php');
?>
```

in the index page do below stuff:

```
<?php
if(!empty($_SESSION['msg']) && isset($_SESSION['msg'])){
echo $_SESSION['msg'];
unset($_SESSION['msg']);
}
?>
```

this will show your message once and unset it immediately.